# AWS CLI Unable to Create RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am following an AWS lambda tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-rds-mysql.html and the first step is to create an RDS instance via the CLI but I am getting the following error...

Invalid endpoint: https://rds.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

I've tried specifying a couple other parameters such as --availability-zone, -vpc-security-group-ids, etc but it still is saying the endpoint doesn't exist?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the region you've setup. Could you please run `aws configure` and provide the required information then give it another shot. Please do note that ENV variables override config files.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the AWS CLI tool installed. It sounds like you have an older version before `us-east-2` was added. You can check the version you have installed by running `aws --version`

Comment: I've upgraded the awscli and now it is at 1.16.34. I have configured aws cli with a default region of us-east-2. I think upgrading fixed my issue because I am getting an error about no default subnet detected in VPC.

Comment: This fixed my issue, the other error was because I deleted my default VPC.

Comment: @MarkB Can you submit your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of the AWS CLI tool installed. It sounds like you have an older version before `us-east-2` was added. You can check the version you have installed by running `aws --version`.